# Pynamodb - Dynamic JSON serialisation

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

I have a composite model which looks like this:-

```
class Parser(MapAttribute):
    ParserType = UnicodeAttribute()
    MailBody = UnicodeAttribute()
    BestTemplate = UnicodeAttribute(null=True)
    ParseStatus = ParseStatus()
    ParsedOutput = JSONAttribute()


class OMPStatusModel(Model):
    """
    PynamoDB Model handling table OMPStatus
    """


    class Meta:
        table_name = 'OMPStatus'
        region = 'us-east-1'
    SNSMessageID = UnicodeAttribute(hash_key=True)
    CreatedDateTime = UTCDateTimeAttribute()
    UpdatedDateTime = UTCDateTimeAttribute(null=True)
    CompletedDateTime = UTCDateTimeAttribute(null=True)
    ProcessStatus = UnicodeAttribute()
    ErrorDetail = UnicodeAttribute(default="Not set")
    SES = SES(null=True)
    SNS = SNS(null=True)
    Parser = Parser(null=True)
```

This works well except the ParsedOutput is stored as a list of key value pairs in DynamoDB. I want to make it easy to read for the support team and want to break it out into its own list of attributes - assume they can all be UnicodeAttribute() for the sake of discussion.

I was thinking i should be able to do something like:-

```
class MyMapAttribute(MapAttribute):
    my_internal_map = MapAttribute()


class Parser(MapAttribute):
    ParserType = UnicodeAttribute()
    MailBody = UnicodeAttribute()
    BestTemplate = UnicodeAttribute(null=True)
    ParseStatus = ParseStatus()
    ParsedOutput = MyMapAttribute(default = {})
```

Then do something like:-

```
OMPStatusModel.update(actions=[OMPStatusModel.SES.set(kwargs[key]),
                          OMPStatusModel.UpdatedDateTime.set(datetime.now())])
```

Not quite getting it as its not quite working.
Any pointers?

Comment: What do you mean by `not quite working`? Anyway, don't do this `WhateverAttribute(default = {})`. Instead, if the type of the `default` is mutable, then do `WhateverAttribute(default=lambda: {})`

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately this was down to me not passing the right object to the Map. Once i did that it worked fine.